# Differences between methods in PHP and Ruby

Tags: php, function, oop, methods

I'm just beginning to learn PHP. Sorry, if it's a newbie question but I'm wondering how methods work. For example, if I wanted to remove white spaces at the beginning of a string. In Ruby, I would call something like:

```
string.strip!
```

But in PHP, I would have to do something like:

```
trim(string);
```

Obviously, the Ruby version is more elegant(in terms of object-oriented design), but I'm wondering how it works for PHP and other languages such Java. Is there a name for designing functions/methods this way(in PHP)? And where are those methods defined and why can they be accessed anywhere? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: PHP is not fully object oriented. You can write it, but PHP itself is not. Some people like to call it object capable. */me ducks for cover*

Comment: Don't look at PHP when you look at better languages too much.

Comment: @PeeHaa: Fair enough; I retract my comment :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two different paradigms here: *object-oriented programming* (OOP) and *procedural programming*.

In OOP, functions are defined in the context of data, encapsulated by **classes**; such functions are usually called **methods**. When a method is called on an object (e.g. an instance of a class), it inherently has access to the state of that object. So, in your example, `strip` already knows what string it's being called on, and so doesn't require any additional arguments. Whenever your function naturally operates on a particular object or set of data (e.g. as `strip` acts on a string), it is sensible to define it as an instance method in this way.

In procedural programming, functions are defined independently data structures (classes), and must be explicitly passed the data they are to work with. Sometimes this approach is in fact more natural; for example, a `print` function that prints some input to `stdout`, or similar, isn't naturally associated with any particular object or data.

Most modern languages have OO features built into them, as it's a very versatile and powerful programming paradigm. Languages like Java and C# encourage all code to be written in an object-oriented style. In these languages, even the basic data-types like strings and floating points are in fact objects and have their own methods and state. This is particularly true in C#, where *all* types inherit ultimately from `System.Object` (even `int` and `double`) and inherit all the common methods defined thereby. This is called a *unified type hierarchy*.

PHP, on the other hand, has a curious mixture of OOP and procedural features; it started life as a procedural language, and OOP was only introduced in version 3 (and only in a very rudimentary sense). While, as of PHP5, it has relatively good OOP support, most of its standard library is still implemented procedurally as loose collections of functions that expect to have the relevant state/data passed to them as arguments. OOP libraries are becoming more common, however (e.g. with `mysqli`).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. But one question though, in procedural programming, how exactly are the functions organized? Since they're not attached to classes, are they grouped into modules or are they all just defined globally? Thanks again.

Comment: Depends on the language. In PHP, they're all defined in the global namespace by default (indeed, until version 5.3, PHP had *only* the global namespace). However in Python, for example, each module has its own namespace (though some special functions exist in the global namespace).

Answer (score 2):

You're looking at, essentially, the different between instance methods and class/static methods. Instance methods are called on a specific instance of a class, and they have access to the internal state of that instance. Class/static methods are not, and do not.

---

I'm not sure what you're looking for in asking "how it works for PHP and ... Java." With regard to instance vs non-instance methods, Ruby, PHP, and Java all work roughly the same.

Comment: I mean, how come I can use it by calling it directly like trim() and not like Class.method format?

Comment: Because PHP - unlike, say, Java - does not _require_ that functions be tied to a class, it merely _allows_ that. Put another way: it's simply the way the language is designed. Python works similarly; functions can, but are not forced to be, tied to classes or instances of a class.